# How do i Search for a certain elementID from webbrowser?

Tags: c#

I'm using c# and i'm very new at these. How to i find an elementID from a webbrowser? If found, return true and else false.

I WANT TO SEARCH FOR ELEMENT IF IT EXIST OR NOT.

Comment: use javascript: document.getElementById('')

Comment: `i'm very new at these` very new at Google?

Comment: How do i search for the element if it exist or not? then return a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it works:

```
HtmlElement emailField = webBrowser1.document.GetElementById("yourelementID");
```